# How to copy an image from screenshot's markup?

Tags: macos, markup

When I capture a screenshot with <kbd>Cmd + Shift + 5</kbd>, I can edit the image within Apple's Markup editor, like so:

[image]

Is there a way to copy that image (which may have been edited) without saving it?

I just need to be able to copy it within that interface, so I can delete it clicking in the trash icon in the upper-right corner.

Comment: [Sindre Sorhus](https://twitter.com/sindresorhus) [has just released](https://twitter.com/sindresorhus/status/1303800142567477250) an [application called Shareful](https://apps.apple.com/app/id1522267256) that does exactly this.

Comment: It's incredible how unclear and unintuitive the markup application is. I have now clue what the "Done" button does (labelled "OK" in your screenshot): does it copy the result somewhere? It doesn't even seem to be an application (the current application title in the macos' menu bar remains set to the underlying application), so it's even hard to google how to use this unnamed thing :-)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

It appears you can just hit <kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>c</kbd> while in the Markup editor and it copies it to your clipboard!

So summary of steps:

- Type <kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>4</kbd>
- Click and drag the crosshairs to capture an area. Or, remember you can capture a whole window by hitting <kbd>space</kbd> and then clicking your mouse.
- Click the little preview image that just popped up in the bottom right of your screen
- Mark up the image as desired
- On older versions of macOS, before <kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>c</kbd> will work, you must click somewhere, in a non-marked up area, to unselect any markup tool in use (pen, figure, etc)
- **Type <kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>c</kbd>**
- Focus on another application and type <kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> it somewhere to paste it.
- Once you know it worked, click the trash can icon in the screen capture tool to make it go away, without saving

I used these steps just now to paste this image:

[image]

I am on Mojave/10.14. I came here looking for the same thing. I happened to find [this comment on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/MacOS/comments/bugjk0/share_menu_ie_in_screenshot_news_and_stocks_app/epd2csa?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x) that suggested this.

Edit 2021-10-12: Use <kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>4</kbd> instead of <kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>5</kbd>, I prefer it, but either works. Clarified the step about unselecting markup tools before <kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>c</kbd> would work, however that didn't seem to be necessary anymore for me, now running Big Sur (11.6).

Comment: in new macos you can click `edit>copy` from top bar, if you want to use mouse.

Comment: @Ali Waqas: Hi and thanks for the suggestion! Are you talking about macOS 14 (Sunburst, still in beta, expected later this year)? If so, looking forward to it. I'm on 13.4.1 and there is still no menu bar for the Screenshot app.

Comment: No i meant the current 13.4 (Ventura) version. Once on markup screen, you will see the top bar and can copy from there.

Comment: @AliWaqas: Hmm, I'd love it if it were there for me, but I don't see it. Maybe it's me. Feel free to post another answer!

Comment: By top bar i mean the `menu bar` as shown [here](https://shorturl.at/CFR35).

Comment: What an incredibly bad design for an interface. Dark pattern after dark pattern. When the Windows Snipping Tool is running circles around you, you have ISSUES!

Answer (score 2):

Unless I'm misunderstanding your question, why not just use <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>4</kbd> to select the marked up image and take a screenshot before deleting it?

Or, if what you're wanting to do is copy it to the clipboard, add the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> key to the keyboard shortcut. That is, by using <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>command</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>4</kbd> you can select the marked up image and take a screenshot but instead of it being saved to your drive, it'll just be copied to the clipboard allowing you to use <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> to paste it.

Comment: Yes, I know about `Cmd + Shift + 4`. The problem is: when I need to edit the screenshot with Markup, how I can copy the edited image?

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain it clearly enough in my answer, but what I'm saying is just do what you're already doing but then when you want to copy the marked up image, take another screenshot of *that* image while it's still in the editor. And, if you use CTRL+CMD+SHIFT+4 to do it, then it'll be copied to your clipboard instead so you can paste it just like you copied it with CMD+C.

Comment: Ah, sorry! I did not understand what you've said. :P Thanks for explaining again with other words. But actually I already do that! I created this question to know if there's a "more elegant" way to copy the edited screenshot.

Comment: Screenshotception? ;)

Comment: @Monomeeth do you have suggestions for doing this with full-screen screenshots? The markup window scales down the screenshot (so that there's room for the toolbar, etc.), and so taking a screenshot of that loses some clarity/resolution.

Comment: @penguinrob Hmm, sorry, nothing that comes to mind just now. But if I think of something I'll ping you. :)